# Symfony 6.2: "Missing value for primary key" when access to collection (OneToMany)

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have a group with an attribute for collection to detail list. Access to group works but  When I access to the linked collection there outputs

> Missing value for primary key langId on App\Entity\AccessoryGroup

I cannot find any solution. Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is my code:

AccessoryGroup.php

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: AccessoryGroupRepository::class, readOnly: true)]
class AccessoryGroup
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: "NONE")]
    #[ORM\Column(name: "accessory_group_id" , type: "string", length: 10, nullable: false)]
    private string $accessoryGroupId = "";

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: "NONE")]
    #[ORM\Column(type: "string", length: 2, nullable: false, options: ["default" => "DE"])]
    private string $langId = "DE";

    #[ORM\Column(type: "string", length: 50, nullable: false)]
    private string $title = "";

    #[ORM\Column(name: "last_update", type: "datetime", columnDefinition: "DATETIME default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")]
    private DateTime $lastUpdate;

    #[ORM\OneToMany( mappedBy: "accessoryGroup", targetEntity: "AccessoryPart")]
    private Collection $accessoryPartList;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->accessoryPartList = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /** getters **/
    ...

    /**
     * @return Collection
     */
    public function getAccessoryPartList(): Collection
    {
        return $this->accessoryPartList;
    }

}
```

AccessoryPart.php

```
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: AccessoryPartRepository::class, readOnly: true)]
class AccessoryPart
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: "AccessoryGroup", inversedBy: "accessoryPartList")]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "accessory_group_id", referencedColumnName: "accessory_group_id", nullable: false)]
    private ?AccessoryGroup $accessoryGroup = null;

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: "Articles")]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "article_part_id", referencedColumnName: "article_id", nullable: false)]
    private ?Articles $articlePart = null;

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: "Manufacturers")]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "manufacturer_part_id", referencedColumnName: "manufacturer_id", nullable: false)]
    private ?Manufacturers $manufacturerPart = null;

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: "Articles")]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "article_accessory_id", referencedColumnName: "article_id", nullable: false)]
    private ?Articles $articleAccessory = null;

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: "Manufacturers")]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: "manufacturer_acc_id", referencedColumnName: "manufacturer_id", nullable: false)]
    private ?Manufacturers $manufacturerAcc = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: "integer", nullable: true, options: ["default" => 0])]
    private int $flag = 0;

    #[ORM\Column(name: "last_update", type: "datetime", columnDefinition: "DATETIME default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")]
    private DateTime $lastUpdate;

    /** getters *//
}
```

AccessoryGroupRepository.php

```
/**
 * @param $articleId
 * @param $language
 * @return AccessoryGroup[]
 */
public function getAccessoryFromPart($articleId, $language): array
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('ag')
        ->where('ag.langId = :lng')
        ->setParameter('lng', $language)
        ->distinct()
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

In my controller

```
$accessoryGList = $agr->getAccessoryFromPart($articleId, $this->sesCustomer['lang'] ?? "DE"); // result valid, two rows back as array
echo "Size: ".sizeof($accessoryGList[0]->getAccessoryPartList()); // <== ERROR
```

Comment: It looks like its because of multiple IDs. But how to handle this?

Comment: Try using `$a->count()` on that collection instead of `sizeof($a)`

Comment: @Jonathan same effect.

Comment: your problem lies deeper than the given code can reveal.